# Losing internet connection sometime after logging in

Tags: windows-7, internet

I am facing a strange issue of losing internet connectivity sometime after logging in. The only workaround seems to be restarting the system. Other systems on the wireless network sharing the internet connection works well.

I ran an avg scan, but it could not find any issues.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Prepare to enter a world of pain, my friend. In my experience you don't troubleshoot this as Windows never gives you enough information to even form a hypothesis.

Comment: You mention AVG, are you running the ZoneAlarm firewall as well?

Comment: yes, zonealarm+avg.

Answer (score 1):

You might research what applications you have running. (it took me a while to realize utorrent was causing me network and connectivity issues) you can also right click on the connection icon in the lower right corner and then left click 'Troubleshoot problems', maybe Windows knows whats wrong.

Comment: @jonthexiii +1 for "maybe Windows knows whats wrong." You should do standup! <rant about Windows Troubleshooter />

Comment: You'd think if Windows had shut off the stupid network, it would know that, and maybe not go thru the whole ruse about "repairing" it?

Answer (score 1):

Any chance that it's happening after being idle a bit?  Windows 7 has different options to turn off components - in my case, it was turning off the network after 20 minutes.  I disabled all the power saving settings, except for the screen saver/monitor off, and my network is no longer dying.

Comment: Yes, it is happening after a period of inactivity (of internet). But I checked the power saving options. It is set to High Performance for Wireless card.

Comment: Turn it off completely, and see if that makes a difference.  Reboot after making changes, and verify that the change sticks.

Answer (score 0):

You might have luck checking the Windows Event Log (Event Viewer, under Administrative Tools in the Control Panel). My old laptop had a bug in the firmware which would cause the driver to restart periodically. After some time of use (usually 10-30 minutes), the driver would get to the point that it would restart every 2-5 seconds, making the wireless card impossible to use until I rebooted.

Comment: The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the stopped state. -- going by the time stamp, it looks like this was logged around the time internet stopped working last. Any clue?

Comment: When you lose connectivity, are you just referring to your webbrowser? Does your wireless disassociate from the access point? Can you still `ping google.com` on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with using both AVG and Zone Alarm firewall.  This may have been resolved by now with updates.  The problem was with using the AVG link scanner component along with Zone Alarm firewall.  Unfortunately, disabling link scanner isn't enough and link scanner can't be separately uninstalled.  The solution that worked for me was to uninstall AVG and then do a custom install but don't install the link scanner component.  It wouldn't take long to give this a try.

You could also check for updates on Zone Alarm.  I believe there was a recent ZoneAlarm update and I saw a favorable review.